# no internet - broadcom NetXtreme BCM755 linux

Tags: linux, internet, broadcom

i have opensuse 11.0 on a PC with Broadcom NetXtreme BCM 755 ethernet adapter. i am not able to connect to the internet. what could be the problems. how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working. the default gateway and dns server had not been configured correctly.